# Unwanted node_modules folder causing issues after switching branches in a Git repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-branch

I have a Git repository with multiple branches, specifically main and branch1. On branch1, I created a React app named "Login," implemented its features, and committed the changes. When I switch back to the main branch, which only contains a README file, I notice that a Login/node_modules folder is present. This is causing problems in Visual Studio Code, displaying over 10K+ git changes and leading to system crashes.

How can I resolve this issue and prevent the node_modules folder from being present on the main branch when switching branches?

Certainly, let's break down the steps you've followed:

1. **Deleted `node_modules` on `branch1` before switching to `main`:**

   - Ran the command: `rm -rf Login/node_modules`
2. **Committed the changes on `branch1`:**

   - Executed the following commands:

     ```bash
     git add .
     git commit -m "Remove node_modules on branch1"
     ```
3. **Switched to `main`

   - Switched to the `main` branch: `git checkout main`
4. **Checked and updated `.gitignore` on `main`:**

   - Verified that `.gitignore` on `main` excludes `node_modules/`.
5. **Cleaned the working directory on `main`:**

   - Confirmed a clean working directory: `git status`
6. **Returned to `branch1` and attempted `npm install`:**

   - Switched back to `branch1`: `git checkout branch1`
   - Ran `npm install` on `branch1`.

Despite following these steps, I encountered an error when running `npm install` on `branch1`, and  unable to install the packages needed for the "Login" app to work again.

Comment: `node_modules` should be in your `.gitignore`

Comment: I have a .gitignore in branch and I have node_modules set in that file. still I am getting this issue. Once I checkout branch I am getting that branches folder/node_modules and it is messing up my git control because of 10K+ new changes

Comment: When modifying my "assignment-2" branch, I created a React app ("react-posts-web-app") using cra. I added "/node_modules" to .gitignore to prevent pushing it to GitHub. After completing the app on "assignment-2," I committed and pushed to "origin/assignment-2," excluding "node_modules." but, in VS Code, the local "assignment-2" branch showed the app folder "login w/node_modules." When switching to the "main" branch, I encountered an issue where "login/node_modules" was present, resulting in over 10K+ changes according to Git.

How to fix avoid having "node_modules" on my local "main" branch?

Comment: pretty sure that's just how git works? why are you working on what sounds like very separate projects in the same repo in separate branches?